# Where to start with UVW files and adding them to a object

Tags: texturing, uv

so I have ordered a model and textures from someone and they have sent me over the .fbx file containing the model. He has also sent 3 uvw files. I know it has something to do with wrapping or unwrapping but I dont know what to search to learn how to do this? Any help would be helpfull. Thak you.

Comment: FBX preserves UV coordinates by default, so shouldn't need any discrete UV files.

Answer (score 0):

You don´t add them to an object previously treated with uvw maps. If they are present and not knowing what kind of obects is, is somewhat difficult. But, you can check the uvw maps appplied to the object in the corresponding uvw editor in Blender. For that you need to go into edit mode and select all the faces as shown in the screenshots[image].
In order to select all faces and don´t miss anyone go into wireframe mode which is the first sphere in the shade view as shown in the second screenshot in the upper right part of the screen. [image].